# How can i make heightFactor fixed in all column items whatever the item height it self changed

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to overlap items in column like following

[image]

depending on **@–pskink comment**

> wrap your Containers with Align with heightFactor < 1

so i tried to make the following

```
  return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 200,
              height: 100,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              heightFactor: 0.8,
              child: Container(
                width: 150,
                height: 100,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              heightFactor: 0.8,
              child: Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 500,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  borderRadius:BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
    );
```

it work prefect but the problem is that heightFactor does not giving the same heightFactor to all items .. for example if item 3 it's height is 500 so the heightFactor does not the same with item 2 that its height is 100 .. How can i make the heightFactor gives fixed overlap to all items whatever the items height is difference ? you can imagine this like normal column but with fixed overlap to all items

Comment: you can use stack instead of column